# How to open ports on azure virtual machine?

Tags: azure, port, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I set a new port by Add EndPoints option but it does not open that specific port on azure virtual machine.... i checked using following link 
can any one tell me how to resolve this issue?

http://postimg.org/image/wb5rid6ib/

TCPSockets endpoint is not open on my virtual machine

Answer (score 3):

Add-AzureEndpoint opens a port at the Azure firewall not your at your VM's side. That means after opening the port in Azure, you have to open the port at your VM's individual firewall, too. Depending on your operating system that could be done differently. E.g. in Windows Server you would configure the Windows Firewall.

More precisely, Add-AzureEndpoint create a port forwarding rule from the specified public port to the private port you have specified for your VM.

Comment: yes i  configure the firewall to allow specific port ,but still port status is closed?

Comment: ok, let's troubleshoot. (a) How do you check whether the port is open? (b) Have you checked internally that the port is open? You could create a second VM in the same virtual network or cloud service try to connect internally. If that fails, you know that the port is not open at your VM. If that succeeds, you know you have to look for an issue at Azure.

Comment: i check through portchecker (yougetsignal.com) the stutus is closed.In my VM Other 3 port that are rdp ,powershell and  iis server there stutus showing OPEN

Comment: Have you checked with portchecker because your software had no connection to your service? Azure uses software defined networks. I am not sure if classic network tools behave the same with Azure. (For example, Azure does not support ping via ICMP.)

Comment: yes i had checked through portchecker the status is closed....!!! i think i'm doing some thing wrong while opening port through vm(ws server 2012 )

Comment: one more thing is that when i  use psping to my internal ip it shows me successfull connection and when i use public ip the ping completed unsuccessfully!!! here is the image to prove? [link](http://postimg.org/image/jwanzqwnl/)

Comment: You did the psping inside the same machine. Your connection did not leave the VM. This way you cannot test, whether you have opened the port in the firewall on the server. (You did open the port in the Windows Firewall, right?) Please try from a another VM in your cloud service. <-- It is important that you put the other VM in the same cloud service as the VM you want to access.

Comment: hey peter....can you please tell me more simpler way i cannot create another cloud service....from my subscription?  and  "firewall on the server" ??? i think there is only windows firewall? and i dont know about any other firewall you taking about ....?